# The unpredictable wrapping habits of CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

I got this simple setup with 3 elements in a flex-box. They are justified space-between. The middle .center element is set width 100%. For some reason the children elements (links) wrap, no matter how wide the window is.

**What is the mechanism behind the result being that the links are being wrapped to the next line?** There is enough space. Why isn't the .center div taking 100% of the left over space so they don't wrap. And how do I prevent this wrapping?

PS: I want the .center div to take 100% of the space in between.

```
<div class="header">
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="center">
  <h1>
    TEST TEXT
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <a>A Link</a>
    <a>Another Link</a>
    <a>A Third Link</a>
</div>
```

```
.header {
    background: #ccc; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav{

  width: fit-content;
}

.center{
  width:100%;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

div a{
  background: tomato;
}
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vsx239v1/

Comment: prevent wrapping is easy, simply need `flex:1` http://jsfiddle.net/vsx239v1/1/ ... for the reason it's more tricky

Answer (score 1):

To understand why your nav elements are wrapping, you need to understand how flexbox works. I am going to explain this briefly with simple words but below you will find a reference with a complete and precise explanation.

Initially, you have set one item to take 100% of width and you kept everything else as default values. The important values used here are:

- `flex-wrap:nowrap` (by default the flex items will not wrap)
- `flex-shrink:1` (by default the flex items will shrink)
- `min-width:auto` (by default the flex items [will not shrink past their minimum content size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size))
- `flex-grow:0` (by default the flex items will not grow)

In your case it's clear that we have overflow since one element is set to `width:100%` and the other to auto BUT the flexbox mechanism will shrink your element and will distribute the **negative free space**<sup>1</sup> to the flex items in order to avoid the overflow.

In your case the first element `h1` can no more shrink since its `width` is equal to its min-content so only your `.center` element and the nav will shrink and this will happen whataver the size of the browser is because we will always have **negative free space** since the `.center` element is set to `width:100%`.

If for example you set `flex-shrink:0` to the nav element you won't have wrapping because you disable the shrink for this one and all the negative free space will be added to the `.center` element *(this can be a fix, but not the best one)*

```css
.header {
    background: #ccc; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
h1 {
 font-size:11px;
}

.center{
  width:100%;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  flex-shrink:0;
}

div a{
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="center">
      <h1>
        TEST TEXT
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <a>A Link</a>
        <a>Another Link</a>
        <a>A Third Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you disable the shrink factor for all the elements **we will have an overflow** because the negative free space will not be distributed:

```css
.header {
    background: #ccc; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
h1 {
 font-size:11px;
}

.center{
  width:100%;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.nav {
  flex-shrink:0;
}

div a{
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="center">
      <h1>
        TEST TEXT
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <a>A Link</a>
        <a>Another Link</a>
        <a>A Third Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you set `flex-wrap:wrap` on the container we will no more consider negative free space and shrinking as if there is no enough space the elements will wrap:

```css
.header {
    background: #ccc; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
h1 {
 font-size:11px;
}

.center{
  width:100%;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

div a{
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="center">
      <h1>
        TEST TEXT
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <a>A Link</a>
        <a>Another Link</a>
        <a>A Third Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

In order to fix all this you need to avoid having negative free space and make the total width to not exceed the container width. Instead of using `width:100%` you can consider `flex-grow` property that will allow an item to grow in order to fill the free space.

```css
.header {
    background: #ccc; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
h1 {
 font-size:11px;
}

.center{
  flex-grow:1;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
div a{
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="center">
      <h1>
        TEST TEXT
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <a>A Link</a>
        <a>Another Link</a>
        <a>A Third Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a good link to better understand the flexbox algorithm considering all the properties : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax

---

<sup>(1) **Negative free space**: We have negative free space when the natural size of the items adds up to **larger than the available space** in the flex container.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `flex-grow: 1` instead of `width: 100%`.

Also `width: fit-content;` is useless here:

```css
.header {
    background: #ccc; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.center{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

div a{
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="center">
  <h1>
    TEST TEXT
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <a>A Link</a>
    <a>Another Link</a>
    <a>A Third Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: he made a part of text bold to highlight the question, so why you remove it?

Answer (score -2):

Change 100% to auto;

```
.center{
 width:auto;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

CSS will always follow your 100% width, making the title and the link adjust, thus the wrapping.